# In sync.Map is it necessary to use Load followed by LoadOrStore for complex values

Tags: go, concurrency

In code where a global map with an expensive to generate value structure may be modified by multiple concurrent threads, which pattern is correct?

```
// equivalent to map[string]*activity where activity is a
// fairly heavyweight structure
var ipActivity sync.Map

// version 1: not safe with multiple threads, I think
func incrementIP(ip string) {
  val, ok := ipActivity.Load(ip)
  if !ok {
    val = buildComplexActivityObject()
    ipActivity.Store(ip, val)
  }

  updateTheActivityObject(val.(*activity), ip)
}

// version 2: inefficient, I think, because a complex object is built 
// every time even through it's only needed the first time
func incrementIP(ip string) {
  tmp := buildComplexActivityObject()
  val, _ := ipActivity.LoadOrStore(ip, tmp)
  updateTheActivity(val.(*activity), ip)
}

// version 3: more complex but technically correct?
func incrementIP(ip string) {
  val, found := ipActivity.Load(ip)
  if !found {
     tmp := buildComplexActivityObject()

     // using load or store incase the mapping was already made in 
     // another store
     val, _ = ipActivity.LoadOrStore(ip, tmp)
  }
  updateTheActivity(val.(*activity), ip)
}
```

Is version three the correct pattern given Go's concurrency model?

Comment: This doesn't look like a use case for `sync.Map`, and you should probably follow the documentation advice about using a simple map and mutex. You also primarily need mutual exclusion around the activity values which none of these solutions show, though may be it's included in the `updateTheActivity` function.

Comment: Where could one find those docs @JimB

Comment: [`sync.Map`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map), trying to sort out what you're doing here, `sync.Map` might not be too bad, just remember that it can't protect the activity values themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 obviously can be called by multiple goroutines with a new `ip` concurrently, and only the last one in the `if` block would get stored. This possibility is greatly increased the longer `buildComplexActivityObject` takes, as there is more time in the critical section.

Option 2 works, but calls `buildComplexActivityObject` every time, which you state is not what you want.

Given that you want to call `buildComplexActivityObject` as infrequently as possible, the third option is the only one that makes sense.

The `sync.Map` however cannot protect the actual `activity` values referenced by the stored pointers. You also need synchronization there when updating the `activity` value.