# LoadOrStore in a sync.Map without creating a new structure each time

Tags: go, concurrency

Is it possible to `LoadOrStore` into a Go [`sync.Map`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map) without creating a new structure every time? If not, what alternatives are available?

The use case here is if I'm using the `sync.Map` as a cache where cache misses are rare (but possible) and on a cache miss I want to add to the map, I need to initialize a structure every single time `LoadOrStore` is called rather than just creating the struct when needed. I'm worried this will hurt the GC, initializing hundreds of thousands of structures that will not be needed.

In Java this can be done using [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51103621/in-sync-map-is-it-necessary-to-use-load-followed-by-loadorstore-for-complex-valu

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> [Package sync](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/)
>
> ```
> import "sync"
> ```
>
> [type Map](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map)
>
> Map is like a Go map[interface{}]interface{} but is safe for
>   concurrent use by multiple goroutines without additional locking or
>   coordination. Loads, stores, and deletes run in amortized constant
>   time.
>
> The Map type is specialized. Most code should use a plain Go map
>   instead, with separate locking or coordination, for better type safety
>   and to make it easier to maintain other invariants along with the map
>   content.
>
> The Map type is optimized for two common use cases: (1) when the entry
>   for a given key is only ever written once but read many times, as in
>   caches that only grow, or (2) when multiple goroutines read, write,
>   and overwrite entries for disjoint sets of keys. In these two cases,
>   use of a Map may significantly reduce lock contention compared to a Go
>   map paired with a separate Mutex or RWMutex.

---

The usual way to solve these problems is to construct a usage model and then benchmark it.

For example, since "cache misses are rare", assume that `Load` wiil work most of the time and only `LoadOrStore` (with value allocation and initialization) when necessary.

```
$ go test map_test.go -bench=. -benchmem
BenchmarkHit-4     2     898810447 ns/op        44536 B/op        1198 allocs/op
BenchmarkMiss-4    1    2958103053 ns/op    483957168 B/op    43713042 allocs/op
$
```

`map_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "strconv"
    "sync"
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkHit(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        var m sync.Map
        for i := 0; i < 64*1024; i++ {
            for k := 0; k < 256; k++ {

                // Assume cache hit
                v, ok := m.Load(k)
                if !ok {
                    // allocate and initialize value
                    v = strconv.Itoa(k)
                    a, loaded := m.LoadOrStore(k, v)
                    if loaded {
                        v = a
                    }
                }
                _ = v

            }
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkMiss(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        var m sync.Map
        for i := 0; i < 64*1024; i++ {
            for k := 0; k < 256; k++ {

                // Assume cache miss
                // allocate and initialize value
                var v interface{} = strconv.Itoa(k)
                a, loaded := m.LoadOrStore(k, v)
                if loaded {
                    v = a
                }
                _ = v

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, however. How do you do computeIfAbsent in Go - specifically, only create a new value if it's missing in the map?

Comment: This example defeats the point of using sync.Map in the first place

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
var m sync.Map
s, ok := m.Load("key")
if !ok {
    s, _ = m.LoadOrStore("key", "value")
}

fmt.Println(s)
```

[play demo](https://play.golang.org/p/Z2z69CiVgLC)

Comment: Just fixed my code with the above solution, and reduced used RAM 2x, also cpu was reduced

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution: use sync.Map and sync.One

```
type syncData struct {
    data interface{}
    once *sync.Once
}

func LoadOrStore(m *sync.Map, key string, f func() (interface{}, error)) (interface{}, error) {
    temp, _ := m.LoadOrStore(key, &syncData{
        data: nil,
        once: &sync.Once{},
    })
    d := temp.(*syncData)
    var err error
    if d.data == nil {
        d.once.Do(func() {
            d.data, err = f()
            if err != nil {
                //if failed, will try again by new sync.Once
                d.once = &sync.Once{}
            }
        })
    }
    return d.data, err
}
```